# Adding computed column to existing SQL Server table, how to populate for existing records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL table called dbo.dwstage and it has a few columns (example)..

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DWStage]
(
    [ComDt] [date] NULL,
    [Exp] [money] NULL,
    [Rev] [money] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This table has records...

If I add a computed column to get day out of ComDt using..

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.DWStage
ADD [Weekday] AS (datepart(day,[ComDt]))
```

This works for any new records that are being inserted into the table.

How can I populate this computed column for all existing records in the table? Can someone show me an example?

We are using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Your code works for existing records as well.  Computed columns are calculated when the data is *queried*, so it is always up-to-date for all rows.

Comment: I am going to go get a coffee first next time before posting. :) Thanks.

Comment: [`DateName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `weekday` will return the name of the day of the week, e.g. "Friday". The day of the month, e.g. `30` or `'30'`, can be retrieved using `DatePart` or `DateName` depending on whether you want an integer or string value.

Answer (score 1):

You dont.

See, a computed column does not store data (unless indexed). It is pure metadata. The data is calculated on demand.

As such, there is no need to update anything.

;) You should have seen that when trying it out right after creating it ;)